# Python selenium for write review google maps (selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: invalid locator )

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, iframe, webdriverwait

Goal:

- Write a review of a location on google maps with python and selenium

Stages:

- Login to google account (already successful)
- Go to the review page (already successful)
- Giving 5 stars (not yet successful)
- Give a review (not yet successful)
- Submit a review (unsuccessful)

Problem:

- An error occurred: selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: invalid locator (Session info: chrome=108.0.5359.125)
- Stuck on the page in the following image
  [image]

I've checked inspect to make sure
[image]

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from time import sleep
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\selenium\chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)
# go to login page
driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/login?hl=id")
# write the email address
email = driver.find_element("name", "identifier")
email.send_keys("email@gmail.com")
sleep(2)
email.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
sleep(5)
# write the password
password = driver.find_element("name", "Passwd")
password.send_keys("Password")
password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
sleep(5)
# go to review page
driver.get("https://search.google.com/local/writereview?placeid=ChIJDf8ln6V5ei4REzngJl6HEEc&pli=1")
sleep(8)
driver.find_element("aria-label", "Lima bintang").click()
```

How to solve this problem? At least to click the 5 stars. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That elements block is inside an iframe. So, you need to switch into the iframe to access those elements. So, you code can be as following:

```py
driver.get("https://search.google.com/local/writereview?placeid=ChIJDf8ln6V5ei4REzngJl6HEEc&pli=1")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[not(@aria-hidden)]/iframe[@name='goog-reviews-write-widget']")))
driver.find_element("aria-label", "Lima bintang").click()
```

When finished working inside that iframe do not forget to get out to the default content with

```py
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

if you want to continue your test flow.
Also, instead of all these hardcoded pauses you should use `WebDriverWait` `expected_conditions` explicit waits.

Comment: "wait" is not defined, do you mean WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[not(@aria-hidden)]/iframe[@name='goog-reviews-write-widget']"))) ?

Comment: Right, you can define it before or inline. I will change this code, thanks!

Comment: Yes, I've tried it, but the result is still the same as the first picture.

Comment: Currently I am not near my computer, will try to take a look again later

Comment: I tried doig so but Google doesn't allow me to login. How could you pass this?

Comment: I just logged in as usual, entered my email (https://i.imgur.com/HaSzyAm.png), entered my password (https://i.imgur.com/pG4abUJ.png), then successfully logged in to Google (https: //i.imgur.com/GjCwRYw.png)